# How to test a Floating Action Button in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-testing

I have an Ionic2 project, with the Unit Testing setup based on the [clicker](https://github.com/lathonez/clicker) repository.
I try to use a Floating Action Button in a component but it throws an exception when running the unit tests. I added a FAB to the plain clickr app to demonstrate the error. It is added to page2.html and you can find it in the [fab-error branch](https://github.com/euleule/clicker/tree/fab-error).

When running the tests, the log looks like this.

```
> Clicker@2.19.0 test /Users/rkause/test/clicker
> ng test

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active16 08 2017 12:15:52.892:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
16 08 2017 12:15:52.902:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
16 08 2017 12:15:52.902:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser ChromeNoSandbox with unlimited concurrency
16 08 2017 12:15:52.915:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
54:11-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
69:11-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
16 08 2017 12:16:02.325:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
16 08 2017 12:16:02.541:INFO [Chrome 60.0.3112 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)]: Connected on socket djJaMpA7zKcR5c3jAAAA with id 17408513
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) Pages: Page2 should create page2 FAILED
    TypeError: unRegEvent is not a function
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41527:13
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at UIEventManager.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/gestures/ui-event-manager.js.UIEventManager.unlistenAll (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41526:19)
        at UIEventManager.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/gestures/ui-event-manager.js.UIEventManager.destroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41535:14)
        at FabContainer.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/components/fab/fab-container.js.FabContainer.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:9287:22)
        at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120688:18)
        at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120657:13)
        at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120641:17)
        at destroyView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:121902:5)
        at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:122048:13)
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 14 of 30 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 2.319 secs)
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) Pages: Page2 should create page2 FAILED
    TypeError: unRegEvent is not a function
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41527:13
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at UIEventManager.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/gestures/ui-event-manager.js.UIEventManager.unlistenAll (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41526:19)
        at UIEventManager.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/gestures/ui-event-manager.js.UIEventManager.destroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41535:14)
        at FabContainer.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/components/fab/fab-container.js.FabContainer.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:9287:22)
        at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120688:18)
        at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120657:13)
        at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:120641:17)
        at destroyView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:121902:5)
ERROR: 'Error during cleanup of component', Page2{title: 'Page 2', OK: function () { ... }, alertController: Object{create: function () { ... }}}
```

I tried adding the components by hand, mocking various services but could not figure out what causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionic-mocks Platform mock is defining `Platform.registerListener`, but doesn't have a signature for the function.

https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks/blob/master/src/angular/platform.ts#L26

Adding this line solves the error for me

```
instance.registerListener.and.returnValue(() => {});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have raised a PR on ionic-mocks.